# How to configure DNS for a custom domain for a site running on an Azure VM

Tags: azure

I have a VM in Azure.

On the VM, I have IIS 7.5 running.

On IIS, I have a website set up: http://edi.cloudapp.net/ and this works.

I now need to change the address so that it uses a custom domain, instead of the generic cloudapp.net which is a part of Azure.

I have registered apgedi.com with godaddy as the custom domain.

How do I configure azure to now use this domain name?  Normally, the server would have an ip address, and I would use this address in the DNS records.

But with Azure, I don't know what IP address to use in the DNS record.

I have tried this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2990804) for setting up a custom domain with an azure web site, but my site is not actual azure website - it's a VM running IIS.  So as far as I can tell, it does not apply.

So what do I use for the DNS settings for apgedi.com?

NSLookup tells me the ip address for edi.cloudapp.net is 191.238.40.128

But when I type this directly into the address bar, it give a 404.  So I don't understand how this is working.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes.   This is a valid issue and is still unresolved.

Comment: This is now resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every VM in Azure lives within a cloud service. This cloud service has an public IP. So if you ping edi.cloudapp.net you will see the ping fail because of security reasons Azure VMs have the ping feature turned off ye default. This is not a problem though as you will still see the IP 191.238.40.128.

You do not configure Azure to use the new domain. You need to either create an DNS CNAME with godaddy that points www.apgedi.com to http://edi.cloudapp.net/ or use a DNS A record to point your domain to the IP.